# How can I build a multi model endpoint for ensemble modeling with using my own model containers?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to deploy a multi model endpoint on Amazon Sagemaker, and am working with my own model containers which I created using [scikit_bring_your_own](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own) example. I can train and create endpoint for each of them separately but for example when I try to collect mlp and cart together in multi model endpoint, I get an error which says "The cart,mlp for production variant AllTraffic did not pass the ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint". When I check CloudWatch logs I cannot see anything unusual. **Should I change the container structure for multi model endpoints ?**

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
import os
import boto3
import time
import re
import sagemaker

model_name = "efe-test-model-ensemble-modeling-" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())

cart_hosting_container = {
    "Image": "097916623002.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/snop-mm-cart:latest",
    "ContainerHostname": "cart",
    "ModelDataUrl": "s3://sagemaker-eu-central-1-097916623002/output/snop-mm-cart-2022-03-09-12-47-04-881/output/model.tar.gz",
}

mlp_hosting_container = {
    "Image": "097916623002.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/snop-mm-mlp:latest",
    "ContainerHostname": "mlp",
    "ModelDataUrl": "s3://sagemaker-eu-central-1-097916623002/output/snop-mm-mlp-2022-03-09-12-52-09-267/output/model.tar.gz",
}

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
sm = boto3.client("sagemaker")

inferenceExecutionConfig = {"Mode": "Direct"}

create_model_response = sm.create_model(
    ModelName=model_name,
    InferenceExecutionConfig=inferenceExecutionConfig,
    ExecutionRoleArn=role,
    Containers=[cart_hosting_container, mlp_hosting_container],
)

endpoint_config_name = "TEST-config-ensemble-modelling-" + strftime(
    "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime()
)
print(endpoint_config_name)
create_endpoint_config_response = sm.create_endpoint_config(
    EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name,
    ProductionVariants=[
        {
            "InstanceType": "ml.m5.large",
            "InitialInstanceCount": 1,
            "InitialVariantWeight": 1,
            "ModelName": model_name,
            "VariantName": "AllTraffic",
        }
    ],
)

print("Endpoint Config Arn: " + create_endpoint_config_response["EndpointConfigArn"])

%%time
import time

endpoint_name = "TEST-endpoint-ensemble-modelling-" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
print(endpoint_name)
create_endpoint_response = sm.create_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name, EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name
)
print(create_endpoint_response["EndpointArn"])

resp = sm.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
status = resp["EndpointStatus"]
print("Status: " + status)

while status == "Creating":
    time.sleep(60)
    resp = sm.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
    status = resp["EndpointStatus"]
    print("Status: " + status)

print("Arn: " + resp["EndpointArn"])
print("Status: " + status)
```

It creates two folders in CloudWatch

[log groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCNOC.png)

mlp is:
[mlp log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7qeA.png)

cart is:
[cart log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhiDC.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the code sample provided it looks like you are configuring a multi container with `Direct` invocation. Looking at the logs, I do not see the full output depicting your container is responding with `200`s to `/ping`.

From this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/multi-container-direct.html#multi-container-troubleshooting), *"we recommend that you choose instance types with enough memory and CPU to ensure that there is enough memory on the instance to have all the models loaded"*. I suggest confirming your Endpoint is not overwhelmed by checking the `MemoryUtilization` and `CPUUtilization` metrics in CloudWatch for the Endpoint.